# How do I use system font information to populate a canvas font property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, fonts

I am experimenting with [Node Canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) (an implementation of the HTML5 Canvas in NodeJS), trying to write simple text in different fonts.

I can pull system font data fine using the [`node-system-fonts`](https://github.com/jgilsaa/node-system-fonts#getavailablefonts) library's `getavailablefonts` function which gives me data like

```json
[
  {
    "path": "/Library/Fonts/AcademyEngravedLet.ttf",
    "postscriptName": "AcademyEngravedLetPlain",
    "family": "Academy Engraved LET",
    "style": "Plain",
    "weight": 400,
    "width": 5
  },
  {
    "path": "/Library/Fonts/Impact.ttf",
    "postscriptName": "Impact",
    "family": "Impact",
    "style": "Regular",
    "weight": 900,
    "width": 4
  }
]
```

In the Canvas itself I can specify the font info using a `font` string, as documented in [`w3schools.com/TAgs/canvas_font`](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/canvas_font.asp).

```js
import { createCanvas } from "canvas";

import { WIDTH, HEIGHT } from "../config";

const write = (text, font, fontStyle) => {
  const canvas = createCanvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.font = `${Math.abs(WIDTH / Math.PI)}px ${font}`;
  ctx.fontStyle = fontStyle;
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText(text, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, WIDTH - 20); // text, x, y, max width

  return canvas;
};
```

But I'm struggling to correctly associate the Font `family` and `style` from the font data with what ought to go into the `ctx.font` property.

In the case of Impact, a font string `200px Impact` gives me a system default font rather than the Impact font.  But `200px Academy Engraved LET` works fine.

Also setting the `ctx.fontStyle` property to the value of the font's `style` property doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there documentation somewhere that explains how to map system fonts to the canvas font property?

Comment: What if you change the font-weight from `400`(default) to `900`? Also you're asking for troubles using such decimal numbers. Round this up, anyway the UA will do it for you (if it did accept it in the first place). And `WIDTH` will probably never be negative, otherwise your `createCanvas` would throw, so you can get rid of the `abs()`. All in all, try with `ctx.font = \`900 ${Math.round(WIDTH / Math.PI)}px ${font}\`;` (note that I couldn't reproduce on my side).

Comment: Thanks - `Math.abs` was an autocomplete error lol.  Replaced with `Math.floor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging around in the actual `canvas` source I've got this working.

```js
/**
 * Convert the font data into a font string.
 *
 * @param {string} size A font size string (eg 100px or 50%/55% etc)
 * @param {object} font The font data, including `{ style, family }`
 * @returns {string} The font string
 */
const stringifyFont = (size, { style, family }) =>
  [style, size, family].filter(Boolean).map(String).join(" ");

export default stringifyFont;
```

I also found it helped to register the fonts as that helped me weed out fonts that, for various reasons, just don't work.

```js
import { registerFont } from "canvas";

const registerFonts = (fonts) => {
  fonts.forEach(({ path, family, weight, style }) => {
    registerFont(path, { family, weight, style });
  });
};

export default registerFonts;
```

Comment: And what do you call that with? What wasn't working wth your original code that this function solves?

Comment: so now I `getAvailableFonts`, then feed that into `registerFonts` then when drawing I just ```ctx.font = stringifyFont(`${Math.floor(WIDTH / Math.PI)}px`, font)```. Works a treat.